# Using tapply on two columns instead of one

Tags: r, plyr, tapply

I would like to calculate the gini coefficient of several plots with R unsing the gini() function from the package reldist.
I have a data frame from which I need to use two columns as input to the gini function.

```
>  head(merged[,c(1,17,29)])
  idp c13     w
1  19 126 14.14
2  19 146 14.14
3  19  76 39.29
4  19  74 39.29
5  19  86 39.29
6  19  93 39.29
```

The gini function uses the first elements for calculation (c13 here) and the second elements are the weights (w here) corresponding to each element from c13.

So I need to use the column c13 and w like this:

```
gini(merged$c13,merged$w)
[1] 0.2959369
```

The thing is I want to do this for each plot (idp). I have 4 thousands different values of idp with dozens of values of the two other columns for each.

I thought I could do this using the function tapply(). But I can't put two colums in the function using tapply.

```
tapply(list(merged$c13,merged$w), merged$idp, gini)
```

As you know this does not work.
So what I would love to get as a result is a data frame like this:

```
 idp  Gini 
1  19 0.12 
2  21 0.45
3  35 0.65
4  65 0.23
```

Do you have any idea of how to do this?? Maybe the plyr package?
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use function `ddply()` from library `plyr()` to calculate coefficient for each level (changed in example data frame some `idp` values to 21).

```
library(plyr)
library(reldist)
ddply(merged,.(idp),summarize, Gini=gini(c13,w))

  idp       Gini
1  19 0.15307402
2  21 0.05006588
```

Comment: Thank you. I definitly need to work on this plyr package. Seems full of interesting functions.